# Modal form submits same data repeatedly

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have a dataTable List with with buttons attached to each row as below:

[image]

Click a button and a Modal form is displayed. The modal is generated dynamically for each row in the table and has different ID.

[image]

I have some validation on one of the fields as so :

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required col-sm-2" for="panel_no">{$smarty.const.TXT_VEHICLE_PANEL}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="panel_no" id="panel_no" required value="{if isset($vehicle)}{$vehicle->panel_no}{/if}" onblur="return verifierPanel_No();">&nbsp;
            <span class="alert alert-popup alert-danger alert-duplication" id="duplication_panel">{$smarty.const.DUPLICATION_PANEL}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The JS function belows does an ajax call to verify duplicates:

```
function verifierPanel_No(){
jQuery("#duplication_panel_no").hide();
var panel_no = jQuery("#panel_no").val();
var vid = jQuery("#vehicle_id").val();
console.log("vid",vid);
console.log("panel",panel_no);
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'vehicle.php',
    data: 'opt=verifierPanel_no&panel_no=' + panel_no + "&vid=" + vid,
    success: function (data) {
        if(data == 1){
            jQuery("#duplication_panel").show();
            jQuery("#panel_no").val("");
            jQuery("#vehicle_form").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }else{
            jQuery("#vehicle_form").submit(function(e){
                jQuery(this).unbind('submit');
            });
        }
    }
});
}
```

THE ISSUE:

The first time from the list: The Modal Opens,
                              Change the field Value,
                              The correct vid and panel_no form the code are posted.

Close the Modal 
Open another Item from the list,
Change the field value,
The same vid and panel_no from the item opened the first time are sent. This is the same on all subsequent items in the list.

Why are the same values being posted? This is not the case when I perform a form submit though.

Answer (score 0):

The `Id` attribute should be unique to the HTML document, from the html and Jquery code you posted it looks like your `Id` attributes are duplicated and so you are not getting the expected result.

There should be only one element with id `panel_no` and `vehicle_id`